# Shell variable is available on command line but not in script

Tags: bash, unix

In the bash command line, I set a variable `myPath=/home/user/dir` . I created a script in which I put `echo $myPath` but it doesnt seem to work. It echoes nothing. If I write `echo $myPath` in the command line, it works, but not in the script.

What can I do to access the `myPath` variable in the script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Export the variable:

```
export myPath=/home/user/dir
```

This instructs the shell to make the variable available in external processes and scripts. If you don't `export` the variable, it will be considered local to the current shell.

To see a list of currently exported variables, use `env`. This can also be used to verify that a variable is correctly defined and exported:

```
$ env | grep myPath
myPath=/home/user/dir
```

Comment: use export var also in your bash profile - if you want your scripts to access these variable. for example JAVA_HOME

Comment: This is misleading.  The `export` has no visible effect on the current shell.  It is useful when the value of the variable needs to be made visible to subprocesses started from the current shell.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed, and unless I'm missing something, that's exactly what the question is asking about: how to access a variable from a subprocess (which is executing a shell script).

Answer (score 23):

how did you assign the variable?  it should have been:

```
$ export myPath="/home/user/dir"
```

then inside a shell program like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $myPath
```

you'll get the desired results.

Comment: If you need to use this inside another quoted string, you can also do echo "Path is ${myPath}"

Answer (score 7):

You could also do this to set the myPath variable just for myscript

```
myPath="whatever" ./myscript
```

For details of the admitted tricky syntax for environment variables see:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/env.html

Answer (score 2):

You must declare your variable assignment with "export" as such:

```
export myPath="/home/user/dir"
```

This will cause the shell to include the variable in the environment of subprocesses it launches.  **By default, variables you declare (without "export") are not passed to a subprocess**.  That is why you did not initially get the result you expected.